# Usar ciertas partes de un archivo JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json, google-cloud-platform, ocr

tengo una duda considerablemente grande y no tengo idea de por donde empezar.

El problema es que tras pasarle la OCR de Cloud Vision de Google al documento que se ve en la foto (aunque sin los recuadros rojos) obtengo un archivo JSON, que adjuntare en un enlace por que tiene mas de 130.000 lineas... Ese archivo JSON lo debe usar un PHP para conseguir devolver todo el texto contenido en los recuadros rojos. He pensado en usar json_decode en el PHP y así tener el archivo JSON dentro del PHP, pero ni si quiera se la forma correcta de usarlo. Como es de esperar los documentos escaneados serán cada vez diferentes y los textos cambiaran relativamente pero el formato sera exactamente igual, lo único que habría que extraer siempre serian los títulos en negrita de los apartados.

[Aquí os dejo en Dropbox el archivo JSON que produce la OCR](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n95d5pk2z0xhwnd/JSON.json?dl=0)

Cualquier tipo de aporte me seria de gran ayuda, estoy totalmente estancado por ahora.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano a todos!

[image: Documento original]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto a obtener el texto, necesitaras usar [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para acceder al campo que tiene el texto.

```
$json = {...AQUI TU ARCHIVO...};
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$texto = $decoded->fullTextAnnotation->text;
```

En la variable `$texto` podrás encontrar el texto que tendrás que parsear para obtener la información que quieres, tal vez deberías abrir otra pregunta, pues desconozco si Cloud Vision puede conservar la información del estilo que parece es como se define el texto de interés.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probare a hacer otra pregunta entonces con el resto de la problematica. Aun asi ha sido de mucha ayuda tu respuesta.